# Let users share posts via Twitter?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, twitter

I am using [Twitter Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-tools/), which allows me to auto-tweet my blog posts. Thats great, but I would also like a button to allow readers to easily tweet them.

<--- What I am talking about is exactly like the little Twitter button next to this question.

How can I add something like that to my blog posts?

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/

is my personal fave for all things tweet related

it does auto post, and can add a tweet button for ya, and a buncha other tings

Answer (score 0):

I have a very lightweight plugin I created that renders the Twitter Tweet and Facebook Like button at the end of each blog post after the content on individual pages and after the excerpt on archive pages.

If you only want to use the Twitter button you can remove the call to the Facebook XFBML in plugin.

You can download from the GitHub page:  https://github.com/c3mdigital/C3M-Social-Share-Buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind making minor modifications to your theme, you can use Twitter's official [Tweet Button Generator](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton) to avoid using a plugin. You can customize the button's appearance and functionality, then just paste the code where you'd like it to appear in your theme.